# I cannot paint using Vertex Paint

Tags: vertex-paint

[image]

Beginner here. I have been following some vid tutorials. But for some reasons. I cant paint on my mesh at vertex paint. Its not visible in render view mode.

[image]

Even though I applied the Attribute node. Please help, How can I fix it???

Comment: Type the name of your vertex colors in the attribute node

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Vertex Color node, with the Vertex Color layer as the text box entry (drop down):

[image]

This will allow you to see the results, if you have the 3D-viewport Shading set to Material Preview or Rendered.

I see lots of tutorials that fail to mention this, perhaps this was some blender 2.8+ addition.